# Compare two timestamp in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

How can I compare this two `timestamp` in oracle SQL

- Date1 = 1420042143
- Date2 = 1412176143

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.date BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2`

Comment: What is the problem with the query you've shown? Other than that you have them the wrong away around?

Comment: What data type are these values? Clearly they're not an Oracle DATE or TIMESTAMP. And what's wrong with the SQL statement you've shown?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are Unix-type epoch-based timestamps stored as numbers, and not real Oracle/SQL timestamps you're formatting in an odd way, what you've shown will work; except the way you've shown it, the values are the wrong way round. [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions012.htm#SQLRF52164):

> If expr3 < expr2, then the interval is empty.

As the `Date1` value you're using as the lower bound is *higher* that the `Date2` value you're using as the upper bound, you won't see any data, even if any rows have values in your range, unless you swap them over:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.date BETWEEN Date2 AND Date1
```

If you are getting these form elsewhere and don't know which will be higher you can use least and greatest to work it out:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.date BETWEEN LEAST(Date1, Date2) AND GREATEST(Date1, Date2)
```

Also note that `between` is inclusive. With some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(epoch NUMBER);
INSERT INTO my_table(epoch) VALUES (1412176143);
INSERT INTO my_table(epoch) VALUES (1417584134);
INSERT INTO my_table(epoch) VALUES (1420042143);
```

the equivalent of your original query finds no data:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE epoch BETWEEN 1420042143 AND 1412176143;

no rows selected
```

Reversing the values finds data, including the upper and lower bound values themselves:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE epoch BETWEEN 1412176143 AND 1420042143;

     EPOCH
----------
1412176143
1417584134
1420042143
```

Comment: Not storing timestamps using the TIMESTAMP data type is just such a bad idea.

Comment: I can just about be OK with storing epoch times, as you can at least constrain them and know they're valid; but only if there's a good reason (like data going in/out to other platforms), and even then I'd be tempted to store the real date/timestamp equivalent anyway - maybe as a virtual column. It's a different magnitude of wrong from storing as strings for instance. But yeah, agree in general, avoid if possible.

Comment: Yeah, the string or formatted number is the one that really should be avoided.